# How to dispatch event in threejs using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just started using Typescript and ran into a problem when working with EventEmitter from the ThreeJS library.

When I try to dispatch an event:

```
const event: THREE.EventDispatcher = new THREE.EventDispatcher();
event.addEventListener('test', () => console.log(1));
event.dispatchEvent({ type: 'test' }); // <-- error
```

[image]

I get an error:

> **TS2345**: Argument of type `'{ type: string; }'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'never'`.

[image]

But it works if I do it like this:

```
const event: THREE.EventDispatcher = new THREE.EventDispatcher();
event.addEventListener('test', () => console.log(1));
event.dispatchEvent<any>({ type: 'test' }); // <-- ignored error by any
```

[image]

But it seems to me that this is a bad solution, could you show me how to do it correctly with explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@types/three` source code includes unit tests that you can read through for usage examples.

I rewrote [one of the EventDispatcher tests](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/284a03f0cffaabc4891aabe25ac377f477a54dc7/types/three/test/unit/src/core/EventDispatcher.ts) to better suit your example:

```
interface TestEvent {
    test: { message: string };
}

const event = new THREE.EventDispatcher<TestEvent>();
event.addEventListener('test', () => console.log(1));
event.dispatchEvent({ type: 'test', message: "hello world" });
```

---

*If you want an in-depth explanation (warning: I'm not a TypeScript guru):*

If you look at the type definitions (e.g. *"Go to Type Definition"* in VSCode/reading the source code/etc.) these are the types:

```
export interface BaseEvent<TEventType extends string = string> {
    readonly type: TEventType;
}

export class EventDispatcher<TEventMap extends {} = {}> {
    // ...

    dispatchEvent<T extends Extract<keyof TEventMap, string>>(event: BaseEvent<T> & TEventMap[T]): void;
}
```

This is what the example code does:

```
// Sets TEventMap type to { test: { message: string } }
const event = new THREE.EventDispatcher<{ test: { message: string } }>();

// This turns to dispatchEvent<"test"> since the key of TEventMap is extracted
// parameter type is now: event: BaseEvent<"test"> & TEventMap["test"]
// which turns to: { type: "test"; } & { message: string; }
// after intersection (&): { type: "test"; message: string; } 
event.dispatchEvent({ type: 'test', message: "hello world" });
```